Multiple Light Probe Planes in EEVEE


I'm working on an dance studio scene in EEVEE. There are mirrored walls on both sides of the room, so I attempted to place two light probe plane objects. However, as shown in the attached image, only one light probe plane seems to function at a time. When I add the second object, the reflection from the first object stops working.
